# while parsing YML to POJO getting exception Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80 (at char #158, byte #-1)

Tags: java, utf-8, yaml, snakeyaml, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I am trying to parse yml file into java object while parsing yml file with object mapper getting below exception.

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.JacksonYAMLParseException:
> java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80 (at
> char #158, byte #-1)  at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:361)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4620)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4469)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3299)

my java code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
XmlConverterProp prop = objectMapper.readValue(configFile, XmlConverterProp.class);
```

yml file

```
dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy=Billing_Date"
lineItemRowNodeName: row
lineItemsNodeName: Mode_Items
removeValueChars: "Net_Amount=$,Unit_Price=Rs.,Item_Amount=€,Gross_Amount=$"
requiredHeaderTags: "cc_BatchDetails,Invoice_Number,Invoice_Date,PO_Number,Document_Type,Vendor_Name,Tax_Amount,Net_Amount,Invoice_Amount,Currency,Gross_Amount,cc_ProfileName,Remit_To_Address_1"
requiredLineTags: "Item_Code,Item_Description,Quantity,Unit_Price,Item_Amount"
```

Comment: Hex 80 is probably the Euro symbol.  That's what it means in some non-utf8 encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic character is the euro sign. Your input is not encoded as UTF-8, since the euro sign is encoded as `0x80`. This corresponds to [IEC_8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) (Latin-9) or [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

YAML requires the input to be one of the UTF-encodings (8, 16 or 32), the most common being UTF-8. You need to encode your YAML file in UTF-8 or one of the others for it to properly load. All code editors provide a way to do this, most have the option in the bottom status bar.